# How to cut only the FIRST character in a string

Tags: php, string

so I have this situation where I want to cut out the first '1.' out of a string, but not any following '1.'s.  I am wondering if this is even possible to do.

So I am converting an it to a string, and I am wondering if there is a way to ONLY cut out the initial '1.' and not any following.

So my script dynamically assigns a number, for example 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 3.1 - based on certain criteria.  And it was currently adding 1. to the beginning of everything. So 1 would = 1.1, 2.1 would = 1.2.1 so on.

Is there a way to force it to ONLY take out the first and not any following? Here is my source:

```
 $str = (string)$i; $str = $i;
 $prepend = $parentPrepend ? 
                 $parentPrepend . '.' . $i 
               : $str = ltrim($str, '\1');
 $i++;
```

Comment: So basically this code is cutting out every '1.' that appears, can someone explain why ltrim is behaving this way? When I research ltrim it says it will cut characters out from the beginning of a string.

Comment: I have tried using substr multiple times but cannot get it to behave the correct way.

Comment: Reminder: The question says he wants to get rid of the first instance of the string "1." not just "1"...the period matters!

Comment: @NicsWorld - You've told `ltrim` to look specifically for `\1` which doesn't exist.  I'm pretty sure you meant to just use `1` instead.  Alternately, you can use `substr($str, 1)` to keep everything after the first character.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `ltrim` code doesn't work is that you are passing in `\1` which is not the same as the character `1`. `\1` refers to the character whose ASCII code is `1` which is not the same as `1` whose ASCII code is actually `\49`.

Modify your code like this:

```
 ltrim($str, '1');
```

That should trim all `1`s from the left of the string.

However, you should know that the `ltrim` will remove all matching characters from the left of the string, not just the first one!

If you want only the first, then you should use `substr` instead, with a test to make sure it is a `1`.

```
if(substr($str, 0, 1) == '1')
    $str = substr($str, 1);
```

And if you want to remove the period too, then simply modify the code to include that (and look at first 2 characters instead of only first character)

```
if (strlen($str) > 2 && substr($str, 0, 2) == '1.')
    $str = substr($str, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you so much for the help.  But this also did the exact same thing.  It removed all 1's from the string.  Meaning that where a record should = 1.1.1, once I use ltrim it is set to 1

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The code in the last paragraph will test if the string starts with 1, and if it does, it will remove that 1 (and only that 1). Is that what you were after?

Comment: I think he's trying to remove the period as well 1.1.1 should become 1.1

Comment: Hi Mike! Thanks for all the help, is len() a pre-defined function in php? I am getting an error saying it is not

Comment: @NicsWorld - when in doubt, always look in the manual. It was a misnomer, the actual function is called strlen. Find the PHP manual here: https://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Answer (score 0):

use strpos to check if 1. is at the beginning. If it is, then use substr to return the string minus the 1.

```
$string = '1.1';

if (strpos($string, '1.') === 0) {
  $string = substr($string, 2);
}

var_dump($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use str_replace with a constraint:

```
$new_string = str_replace ('1.' , '' , $your_string, 1);
```